# Storage object access with docker FTP getting error 550

Tags: linux, docker, ftp, centos, pureftpd

I'm actually using an object storage from scaleway. I want to be able to access it with ftp and be able to do some action. Right now I can access and view files/folders from it, but I can't do action, like rename a file, create a dir...
I'm using CentOS 7 as operating system.
Here is my mounted volume in my host:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 0 Jan 1 1970 mnt
```

I'm using the following command to create a container :

```
docker run -d --name ftpd_server -p 21:21 -p 30000-30009:30000-30009 -e "PUBLICHOST=123.123.123.123" -v /mnt:/home/ftpusers/userA stilliard/pure-ftpd:latest
```

Then I enter in the container with :

```
docker exec -it ftpd_server /bin/bash
```

And I create the user

```
pure-pw useradd userA -f /etc/pure-ftpd/passwd/pureftpd.passwd -m -u ftpuser -d /home/ftpusers/userA
```

Then I get this when I try to create a dir

[image]

And I can see my contents

I'm using `stilliard/pure-ftpd` as the docker image

I also tried to give ftpuser root privilege and change in /etc/pure-ftpd/passwd/pureftpd.passwd to change from 1000.1000 to 0.0 but the problem persist

I also found in their github an issue which is similar to mine https://github.com/stilliard/docker-pure-ftpd/issues/35#issuecomment-325583705 but I can't make it work.

Answer (score -1):

HTTP response code 550 indicated to me the Scaleway object storage user does not have permissions to complete the requested operation. The first place I would look is at Scaleway / remote host user account permissions. My guess is that the user account does not have the required permissions.

Comment: I have also a docker transmission and nextcloud which works perfectly on the same object storage. I can create, add, rename... without any errors